# Natural numeric sort in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a problem when sorting a generic list in C#

I have a `List<MyObjects> myList`, and `MyObject` has a string property.

Now it looks like this when sorting descending

> 2.4.88
>
> 2.4.70
>
> 2.4.164 -> this is wrong
>
> 2.4.15

How do I sort my list?

I have tried:

```
myList.sort(delegate(MyObjects obj1, MyObjects obj2)
{
    return obj2.version.CompareTo(obj1.version);
});
```

Its not an option to use Linq (older framework)

**UPDATE: My list can also contains N/A**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare as strings, because obviously thats the proper string sorting.  You need to parse to numbers or to an instance of the [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class:

```
myList.sort(delegate(MyObjects obj1, MyObjects obj2)
{
    return new Version(obj2.version).CompareTo(new Version(obj1.version));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to do natural sorting a while ago. Don't remember where I found the code, but stuck it on my blog for future reference: http://www.geekality.net/2009/03/02/natural-sorting

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;

namespace NaturalSort
{
     public sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
     {
         private readonly int modifier = 1;

         public NaturalStringComparer(bool descending)
         {
             if (descending)
                 modifier = -1;
         }

         public NaturalStringComparer()
             :this(false) {}

         public int Compare(string a, string b)
         {
             return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(a ?? "", b ?? "") * modifier;
         }
     }

     public sealed class NaturalFileInfoComparer : IComparer<FileInfo>
     {
         public int Compare(FileInfo a, FileInfo b)
         {
             return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(a.Name ?? "", b.Name ?? "");
         }
     }

     [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
     internal static class SafeNativeMethods
     {
         [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
         public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
     }
}
```

You'd use it along these lines:

```
myList.Sort(new NaturalStringComparer(true));
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps sort via Version?

```
return (Version.Parse(obj2.version)).CompareTo(Version.Parse(obj1.version));
```

of course, it will be cheaper if you do the parsing once and once only (maybe make `version` a `Version` instead of a `string`)

Comment: I haven't got any Version.Parse method

Comment: @Millerbean ah, you might have to try the `TryParse` approach, or `new Version(...)`, depending on your framework version.

Answer (score 1):

If your string pattern fits the .Net version class then  convert it to a Version object and [compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ts8tb6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one on these may help you:

- [Natural Sorting in C#](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting)
- [The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

Answer (score -1):

Can you describe how it is wrong. Looks like it is perfectly placed in order. However, just a random suggestion, if you are sure of format you can break the string and convert to number to check this kind of stuff.

Comment: 164 rarely comes between 15 and 70 when sorting naturally

Comment: yes, but if you do string compare it will :). as string compare it does character compare from left to right. Hence to do you either have to convert it to double after break up or follow other comment on version catching.