# c# alphanumeric list sorting by checking if list item contains

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a `List<string>` like this

```
List<string> Test_List = new List<string>()
{
    "ZZA-KG-TEST",
    "ZZA-EG-TEST",
    "ZZA-KL-10A",
    "ZZA-KL-5A",
    "ZZA-KL-1A",
    "ZZA-FG-TEST",
    "RO-ELEVER"
};
```

**Expected** output after sorting

```
List<string> Test_List = new List<string>()
{
    "ZZA-KL-1A",
    "ZZA-KL-5A",
    "ZZA-KL-10A",
    "ZZA-KG-TEST",
    "ZZA-FG-TEST",
    "ZZA-EG-TEST",
    "RO-ELEVER"
};
```

What I am **actually** getting is

```
List<string> Test_List = new List<string>()
{
    "ZZA-KL-1A",
    "ZZA-KL-5A",
    "ZZA-KL-10A",
    "RO-ELEVER"
    "ZZA-EG-TEST",
    "ZZA-FG-TEST",
    "ZZA-KG-TEST",
};
```

My code is this

```
var data = Test_List
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KL-"))
    .ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer())
    .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KG-"))
    .ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer())
    .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-FG-"))
    .ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer())
    .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-EG-"))
    .ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer());

class AlphanumericComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string s1, string s2);

    public int Compare(string x, string y) => StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
}
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT** I need all items containing `-KL-` comes at *top* and then order them withing `-KL-` and same for `-KG-`, `-FG-` and `-EG-` and then the rest

Comment: Why are you doing the alphanumeric sort 4 times?

Comment: You are using the descending order, but how `"ZZA-KL-1A` can be before `ZZA-KL-5A`

Comment: .NET sorting is already alphanumeric. There's no reason to use a Win32 API cal. `.OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KL-"))` and all similar calls make no sense - they just order a `true/false` value, only for that ordering to be lost by the next call to  `.ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer())`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski because it has 1 which is less then 5. So it is suppose to come first

Comment: Is the *real* question perhaps, how to sort using different components of the string? Use different components of the string - split the string, extract the components and use them in the `OrderByDescending` expression

Comment: I think your imported function does it worng and takes `EL` part  of `RO-ELEVER` and considers it as second token in the string, which is used for sorting (as you mentioned). Is `EL` any special in ordering?

Comment: Related: [Natural numeric sort in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430674/natural-numeric-sort-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @mohsinali1317 `because it has 1 which is less then 5. So it is suppose to come first` on the contrary, with descending order it has to come *second*. Unless you want descending order for parts 1,2 and ascending for part 3, if it exists

Answer (score 4):

You, probably, want first to order *groups* (`KL, KG, FG, EG, all_the_rest` in this very order):

```
.OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KL-"))
.ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KG-"))
.ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-FG-"))
.ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-EG-"))
```

And only then order items *within each group*:

```
.ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer());
```

i.e.

```
var data = Test_List
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KL-"))
  .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-KG-"))
  .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-FG-"))
  .ThenByDescending(i => i.Contains("-EG-"))
  .ThenBy(i => i, new AlphanumericComparer());
```

Comment: This makes sense, let me try this one. :)